# Code signing error while building the realm framework for Swift 2.0

Tags: realm, swift2

I'm trying to build the Realm framework for Swift 2.0 by following the steps mentioned in Realm Swift documentation. But as soon as I run the script to build the framework, the following error appears

> Building with command: xcodebuild
>   -IDECustomDerivedDataLocation=build/DerivedData -project Realm.xcodeproj -scheme 'iOS' -configuration Release -sdk iphoneos
>   User defaults from command line:
>       IDECustomDerivedDataLocation = build/DerivedData
>
> Build settings from command line:
>       SDKROOT = iphoneos8.4
>
> === BUILD TARGET iOS OF PROJECT Realm WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===
>
> Check dependencies Code Sign error: No code signing identities found:
>   No valid signing identities (i.e. certificate and private key pair)
>   matching the team ID “(null)” were found. CodeSign error: code signing
>   is required for product type 'Framework' in SDK 'iOS 8.4'
>
> ** BUILD FAILED **
>
> The following build commands failed:  Check dependencies (1 failure)

Can someone help me to solve this error?

Thanks 
Suraj

Comment: As the error points out, it looks like you don't have a team set, which is an issue building in release because it's trying to code sign. Can you make sure to select a team, and verify you have a valid code signing cert for that team?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS8 Dynamic Frameworks -> CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Framework' in SDK 'iOS 8.3'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29836356/ios8-dynamic-frameworks-codesign-error-code-signing-is-required-for-product)

Comment: Hi @segiddins, Just to understand, I'm only trying to build the Realm framework here. Its not part of any projects that I'm working on. So I do not have any bundle id or code signing identity associated to it. I just cloned the Realm repo and checked out the latest swift-2.0 branch. Then as per the documentation, tried to run the build.sh script with "build" parameter. Should I have the code signing identity for the Realm project to make this work?

Comment: @SurajSundar Swift 1.2 and 2.0 code are merged to master now https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/pull/2209. And they are switched automatically depends on current toolchain. If you would like to build the framework for Swift 2.0, you can just execute build.sh in master branch.

Comment: Yeah, `build.sh` requires you to have a signing identity set up, since it by default also builds slices for device